# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch MATLAB error

Tags: matlab

Can anyone help what is the problem in this code?
This is code is used to extract HOG features from image dataset then train model using these features. for classification purpose SVM classifier is used.

```
    train = fullfile('C:\Users\meena\Documents\MATLAB\ImagaData\Train');

    test = fullfile('C:\Users\meena\Documents\MATLAB\ImagaData\Test');
 trainingSet=imageDatastore(train,'IncludeSubfolders',true,'LabelSource','foldernames','FileExtensions','.jfif');

testSet =imageDatastore(test,'IncludeSubfolders',true,'LabelSource','foldernames','FileExtensions','.jfif');

countEachLabel(trainingSet)

countEachLabel(testSet)

img = readimage(trainingSet, 80);

% Extract HOG features and HOG visualization

[hog_2x2, vis2x2] = extractHOGFeatures(img,'CellSize',[2 2]);

cellSize = [2 2];

hogFeatureSize = length(hog_2x2);

numImages = numel(trainingSet.Files);

trainingFeatures() = zeros(numImages,hogFeatureSize,'single');

for i = 1:numImages

img = readimage(trainingSet,i);

trainingFeatures(i, :) = extractHOGFeatures(img,'CellSize',cellSize); 
end

% Get labels for each image.

trainingLabels = trainingSet.Labels;

% fitcecoc uses SVM learners and a 'One-vs-One' encoding scheme.

classifier = fitcecoc(trainingFeatures, trainingLabels);
```

Error

Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in final (line 29)

```
trainingFeatures(i, :) = extractHOGFeatures(img,'CellSize',cellSize);
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message into your question, it indicates where the error happened and why it happened. Without that information, we’d only be guessing about your problem.

Comment: Related recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67552435/7328782

Comment: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.


Error in final (line 29)


  '  trainingFeatures(i, :) = extractHOGFeatures(img,'CellSize',cellSize);'

@CrisLuengo

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the full error message. Comments are not di important information.  Also, explain what the code is supposed to do, see [mre] and [ask].

Comment: @CrisLuengo can you check it now?